# How to speed up search indexing on latitude and longitude

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The stmt below works perfect, it only selects client_id that are within a certain distance(miles).  The problem is that it's extremely slow.
12 seconds to search 1.8 million small records.  And yes, I have created a index on lat and longitude.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT client_id,
 ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(:currentlat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(:currentlon) ) 
+ sin( radians(:currentlat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )   AS distance FROM $live_table

WHERE  (companyname like :name
 OR
   contact LIKE :name
 OR
   yourcategory LIKE :name)
 AND
   is_active != :active_switch
 HAVING distance < :mydistance ORDER BY client_id desc ");
```

A few days ago, I had help from stackoverflow and we came up with the following.  Awsome, now it only takes 3 to 4 seconds. But it's not calculating distance
properly.  It returns the LIKE commands properly, but all of them.  If I select $mydistance to be 20 miles or less, it still show results from 100 miles away.
I have spent hours trying to figure this out and at my witts end.  Please help Again

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT client_id,
 (lat  BETWEEN :currentlat - (:mydistance / 69.0 ) AND :currentlat + (:mydistance / 69.0 )),
  longitude BETWEEN :currentlon - (:mydistance / (111.045 * COS(RADIANS(lat)))) AND :currentlon + (:mydistance / (111.045 * COS(RADIANS(lat))))

FROM $live_table
WHERE (companyname like :name
  OR
   contact LIKE :name
  OR
   yourcategory LIKE :name)
  AND 
   is_active != :active_switch
  HAVING distance < :mydistance ORDER BY client_id DESC ");
```

OK Sloan, I think I understand what you are saying, so I added "AS distance" after calculating lat and longitude and still not working properly

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT client_id,
 (lat  BETWEEN :currentlat - (:mydistance / 69.0 ) AND :currentlat + (:mydistance / 69.0 )),
  longitude BETWEEN :currentlon - (:mydistance / (111.045 * COS(RADIANS(lat)))) AND :currentlon + (:mydistance / (111.045 * COS(RADIANS(lat))))

AS distance

FROM $live_table
WHERE (companyname like :name
  OR
   contact LIKE :name
  OR
   yourcategory LIKE :name)
  AND 
   is_active != :active_switch
  HAVING distance < :mydistance ORDER BY client_id DESC ");
```

Comment: You aren't calculating distance in your 2nd query like you were in the first. You have a boolean expression that will return true or false, so your having makes no sense. Besides that, there isn't a column named distance in your query.